# Google Analytics. Create account and profiles

Tags: java, google-analytics-api

So, I have gmail account. I have google analytics account.

Is it possible to create account ( also, i want to create profile ) via Google Analytics API?

I can't find information about that...

If u know something about that, please notify me.

If my task has no solution, please say to me about that :)

Thanks you! :)

Comment: This might help you .check this. http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/home.html

Comment: I already read that. I suppose that GA API has no ability to management accounts. Am i right?

Answer (score 3):

The [GA Management API](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/mgmt/home.html) is read-only. You cannot create accounts or profiles through it:

> Google Analytics provides developer access to the configuration data through the Management API, which is a read-only API for account and configuration data.